# shell script to traverse files recursively

Tags: shell, scripting, file

I need some assistance in creating a shell script to run a specific command (any) on each file in a folder, as well as recursively dive into sub-directories.

I'm not sure how to start.

a point in the right direction would suffice.  Thank you.

Comment: There's actually hunderds of ways to do this. The best solution depends on your goals, so if you would share it you may get a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To apply a command (say, `echo`) to all *files* below the current path, use

```
find . -type f -exec echo "{}" \;
```

for directories, use `-type d`

Answer (score 8):

You should be looking at the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command.

For example, to change permissions all JPEG files under your `/tmp` directory:

```
find /tmp -name '*.jpg' -exec chmod 777 {} ';'
```

Although, if there are a lot of files, you can combine it with [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to batch them up, something like:

```
find /tmp -name '*.jpg' | xargs chmod 777
```

And, on implementations of `find` and `xargs` that support null-separation:

```
find /tmp -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash 4.0

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.txt
do
  echo "do something with $file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To recursively list all files

```
find . -name '*'
```

And lets say for example you want to 'grep' on each file then -

```
find . -type f -name 'pattern' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'searchtext'
```

Comment: The `-name '*'` is not what you want.  It should be `-type f` to match only files.  And to execute a command, use `-exec`, not a pipe.

Comment: grepping `/dev/urandom` might take a while ;-) I suggest adding `-type f`

Comment: as for grepping you'd better just `grep -R` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Within a bash script, you can go through the results from "find" command this way:

```
for F in `find . -type f`
do
 # command that uses $F
done
```